# how to diable previous dates on angularJS md datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular `md-datepicker` for `startDate` and `endDate`.
I need my `startDate` to equal `currentDate` and disable previous dates. Similarly user can choose `endDate` only after `startDate`.

Comment: Show some code please, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In md-datepicker, you can set the minimum date using `md-min-date`. In your controller you can set a $scope variable like:

```
$scope.today = new Date()
```

and in view just use

```
 <md-datepicker ng-model="startDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-min-date="today"></md-datepicker>
```

And for choosing `endDate` only after selecting `startDate`, you can make use of `ng-disabled` in the second date picker till your `startDate` model is set. So your second datepicker directive will look like

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="endDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-min-date="startDate" ng-disabled="startDate.length == 0"></md-datepicker>
```

Hope this helps.